# Loading raw HTML in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

I have written a couple of live wallpapers in recent weeks using local resources.  Now a potential client wants me to make one that loads and displays the photos (usually between 3 and 10) from his daily news report posted online.  The report file has a URL along the lines of `http://example.com/dailytext/report.html` which loads images along the lines of `http://example.com/dailymedia/obama.jpg`  The references in `report.html` look like
`img src="../dailymedia/obama.jpg" ...`

Am I supposed to use a WebView to do this?  That doesn't seem quite right, because I don't want to display the HTML.  I would think that I want to throw the raw HTML into an array, parse the HTML looking for the instances of `"img src..."`, reconstruct the full URLs, then load the bitmaps.  I'm getting the impression this is more of a pure Java task than anything to do with Android's specialized classes, but I don't know.  Any suggestions about "best practice?"

Comment: I would find out first if there is a way to have the data provided from the server in a better format rather than having to scrape the html. If the server can provide a simple json list of images it would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Point well taken.  Though I accepted Richard's answer, I may well ask the client to put in a little effort to simplify my task.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have misunderstood, this really isn't hard. You need to do the following:

- Fetch the HTML, using either the native java networking api or something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
- Use a parser like [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) or [Dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) to extract out the image links
- Construct the absolute URLs, can be done with just [java.net.URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)
- Fetch the images

Answer (score 0):

You could also prefer using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/)
HTML Parser.